# Отображение тени win forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно добавить тень для формы с `FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None` , 
нашел такой код

```
private const int CS_DROPSHADOW = 0x00020000;
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        // add the drop shadow flag for automatically drawing
        // a drop shadow around the form
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ClassStyle |= CS_DROPSHADOW;
        return cp;
    }
}
```

в комментариях на [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2463573/2211718), пишут что он работает, но у меня почему то нет, что я делаю не так?
П.с что можно подолжить изображение под форму знаю, но есть свои нюансы поэтому хочеться это сделать без изображений и дополнительных форм.

Comment: Может, у вас используются нестандартные атрибуты окна? Попробуйте создать новый winforms-проект с нуля, применить указаный вами трюк и посмотреть, будет ли нужный эффект.

Comment: @VladD, Я на новом окне только и пробывал.

Answer (score 2):

Все у вас верно, у меня идентичный код отлично работает.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            private const int CS_DROPSHADOW = 0x20000;
            protected override CreateParams CreateParams
            {
                get
                {
                    CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                    cp.ClassStyle |= CS_DROPSHADOW;
                    return cp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Для корректной работы кода, который представлен выше, в свойствах границы формы (FormBorderStyle) необходимо выставить значение None.